# Convert < > from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get `<` from a string that contains the character.

So what I want to do is:

`magic_function('<') = <`

in order to make. For example:

`1 magic_function('<') 3`

I expect, of course, that the program returns `True`

Comment: do you mean `eval()`?

Comment: Please include a clean example of your input, the expected output, and the code that you wrote so far.

Comment: Based on what you've posted so far, it looks like you want to create a function that returns an operator. If so, that is not possible. It would help to explain *why* you want to do this.

Comment: @Patrick not exactly. I have a function where you enter a string with wether '<', '>', '!=' or '=='. And I want to avoid the part where you try with an if with all them four. So I want to know if there is this *magic_function* in which I can get < from '<'

Comment: @AntoniaCobo You’re better off with conditional statements (ifs)

Comment: @pushkin I have a function where you have to put a string with the comparison symbol ( '<', '>', '!=' or '==' ) and I have to return the comparison given between two values. I want to skip the part where I have to put four if to get the symbol

Comment: @AntoniaCobo So you want your function to also accept the two values, then. You should just use 4 `if`s. It's the cleanest way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn’t possible with specifically what you want. A function returns an object, not an operator. I’m not sure what your main intention is here but you might want to rethink your architecture.

What you can do (but what I don’t recommend) is using `eval()` like so:

```
eval(“1 < 3”)
```

But there are many resources online about why eval is “evil”: to sum them up, if you don’t know what your data source is, then you could be performing unexpected operations which you might not want.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I need. I am going to find out if this will return **ALWAYS** what I need. By the way, it was not me who downvoted.

Comment: `eval` is bad on its own. suggesting to use it is equally bad.

Comment: Absolutely not. In the case of OP - where you know where your input is sanitised, then `eval` can be justified. If it was bad on its own then why does it exist? The stigma around `eval` needs to be re-evaluated: Don't hate it 100% when there are cases where it's justified

Comment: @TerryA it's honestly a very cool trick, and I'm surprised you're getting heat for it. Adding strings, and then making it a statement that can be evaluated. Top notch! I think the stigma comes from people worried that it's hard to work with corrupt user input, or hard to debug, or that there must be a way around it (to change your code, but you can't change this code. It is a clear and defined goal.) Anyway, good answer! +1